# Separate Css files in typescript react project do not apply

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

My problem is the following, I created a new react project with typescript. And added a custom component that has a separate css file for it's styling. The folder structure is like this:

[image: Folder structure]

In the Header.css I defined a class:

```
.mainHeading {
    color: green;
}
```

And referenced it in the Header.tsx like this:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from './Header.css';

function Header() {
    return(
        <h1 className={styles.mainHeading}>Streamfiuse</h1>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

To do this I added the following to the react-app-env.d.ts

```
declare module '*.css';
```

I'm using the Header component in the App.tsx like the following

```
import React from 'react';
import Discover from './components/discover/Discover';
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Discover />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is now that I would expect the heading "Streamfiuse" to appear in green, but apparently it doesn't. I'm new to react so any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**
I also tried this:

```
import React from "react";
import './Header.css';

function Header() {
    return(
        <h1 className="mainHeading">Streamfiuse</h1>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

But does't work either.

Comment: Did you try to import like this: `import './Header.css';`?

Comment: Yes, I tried the import like this ```import './Header.css';?``` and referencing like this: ```<h1 className="mainHeading">Streamfiuse</h1>```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this:
`import './Header.css'` 
And applying the mainHeading class as a string

Comment: As you can see in my comment on my question I did this already

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this

1. Change `import styles from './Header.css';` into `import './Header.css';`
2. Change `className={styles.mainHeading}` into `className="mainHeading"`

```js
import React from "react";
import './Header.css';

function Header() {
    return(
        <h1 className="mainHeading">Streamfiuse</h1>
    );
}

export default Header;
```